# navigator.clipboard.writeText(...) fails, document.execCommand('copy') works inconsistently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

I have a web page with an iframe, where there's a Copy button on the main page, which messages a function inside the iframe, intended to generate a link and put it in the clipboard, but it doesn't work consistently.
I'm using Chrome.

I made an attempt to use `navigator.clipboard` API, which always fails and `e` is undefined - no reason given for the writeText failure

```
function copyText(text){
  if (navigator && navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.writeText) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(
      () => console.log("Copied text OK"),
      (e) => console.log("Failed to copy text",e)
    );
  }
}
```

Then I tried with code from other posts here

```
 if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
    return window.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
 }
```

The above doesn't run in Chrome, the `if` evaluates to `false`

Another attempt, also from another answer in SO is to create a text element and copy its contents:

```
var tel = document.createElement('textarea');
tel.textContent = text;
document.body.appendChild(tel);
tel.select();

try {
    var isok = document.execCommand('copy');
    console.log("exec(copy) returned:", isok);
} catch (err) {
    console.log("exec(copy) failed", err);
}
finally {
    document.body.removeChild(tel);
}
```

The above code doesn't show a "failed" message in console, but it doesn't set the value in the clipboard either. In those cases `isok` is false. However, if I interact with the page - click something else first - it does work.

I'm testing this with a static `text` value, a link that doesn't change, so the text passed to the function is not different. The function does get called, confirmed with debugger.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does the Iframe even have clipboard permissions? If not, you could try sending a message out back to the main page and let the main page do the copying afterwards. Also, are you sure there is no error or warning displayed in the console with an explanation for the failure? Often the reason is hidden from the caller code but visible to the developer as a log entry. Also please note that usually it requires a user intent (e.g. a click) to allow the copying to take place.

Comment: Once I interact with the iframe, it copies the text it should, I'm starting to think it's conditional. There are no errors in the console

Comment: Are you sure `e` is undefined and there is nothing shown in the console? If I test it, I get a `DOMException` with name `NotAllowedError` and message `Document is not focused.`, just as I expected.

Comment: in my case it's undefined, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to the user action being outside the iframe, while the clipboard was being set inside the iframe.

Chromium requires an user action to allow access to the clipboard, but doesn't track the source of the action across the iframe boundary.

To resolve the issue, I had to move the button inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

If your button is inside of an iframe it won't have access to the definition of your copy function unless it is defined, or loaded into the iframe document.

If you are defining the function in the main/top document, you would be able to run this function in the console but your button would not be able to access the function from inside of the iframe.

Comment: The Copy button is outside the iframe and it sends a message to inside the iframe, where the copying takes place